# Can't run xfdashboard

Tags: 16.04, vnc

I'm trying to run xfdashboard like this:

```
xfdashboard –daemon
```

But it fails with the following error:

```
(xfdashboard:17266): Clutter-CRITICAL **: Unable to initialize Clutter: Unable to initialize the Clutter backend
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

I'm running Running Ubuntu 16.04.4 xenial and I'm connecting to the machine through a VNC session.